# FirebaseUI - get random list using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

Firebase data structure

```
{ "questions" : {
"-KkLGS71meu8aA_wcqTq" : {
  "q_answer" : "....",
  "q_category" : "....",
  "q_qid" : "1",
  "q_question" : "..."
},
"-KkLGkf8tNb-OKwu2qVa" : {
  "q_answer" : "...",
  "q_category" : "...",
  "q_qid" : "2",
  "q_question" : "..."
},
"-KkLH1T1ZhFKJaqYFuJ4" : {
  "q_answer" : "...",
  "q_category" : "...",
  "q_qid" : "3",
  "q_question" : "..."
} }
```

Database refrence

```
questionRef.orderByChild("q_qid")
```

how do i generate random query and display with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?
Is there any other way to do it?

**Edit :**

I try this code

```
questionRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    long allNum = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                    int maxNum = (int)allNum;
                    int minNum = 1;
                    int randomNum = new Random().nextInt(maxNum - minNum + 1) + minNum;

                    int count = 0;
                    Iterable<DataSnapshot> ds = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
                    Iterator<DataSnapshot> ids = ds.iterator();
                    Map<String, Object> question;

                    while(ids.hasNext() && count < randomNum) {
                         question = (Map<String, Object>) ids.next().getValue();

                        String q = question.get("q_question").toString();
                        viewHolder.question.setText(q);

                        count ++; // used as positioning.
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

But some question appear more than once ?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do, is to find out the number of possible values, `numVals` in the database and then use that in the following line of code:

```
int random = new Random().nextInt(numVals);
```

If you are using in your code an iterator to iterate a `DataSnapshot` than just iterate a random number of times to get the required value.

Hope it helps.